# Android SQLite insert into the table does not seam to work as log shows "(1) no column: " error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Trying to do a simple login app, been stuck at this for a while could use some help, I have a separate helper class to override the methods from the super class and also to provide the context, the open method is to getWritable object and open the db, where as the close is to close the db. Insert is to insert into table and getUserId and getPassword are pretty straight forward.

The below code is my DB code:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper{   
private static final String LOGCAT = null;   
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";//db  
private static final String DATABASE_USERS = "Users";//table  
private static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";  
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";  
private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_USERID,KEY_PASSWORD};  
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "create table "+DATABASE_USERS+" ( userid TEXT, password TEXT)";  
private SQLiteDatabase SQLdb;  
private HelperClass helper;  
private final Context mContext;  



public MySQLiteHelper(Context context){
    this.mContext=context;
    helper = new HelperClass(mContext);
}

public class HelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public HelperClass(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase SQLdb){
        try{
            SQLdb.execSQL(TABLE_USERS);
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Table Created");
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Exception arrised");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase SQLdb, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        SQLdb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Table being recreated");
        onCreate(SQLdb);
    }
}

public MySQLiteHelper open(){
    SQLdb = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "DB Opened");
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    helper.close();
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "DB Closed");
}

public long insertUser(String Userid,String Password){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_USERID,Userid);
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, Password);
    open();
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "calling insert");
    long l = SQLdb.insert(DATABASE_USERS,null,values);
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Inserted User profile at column:"+l);
    close();
    return l;
}

public Cursor getUserId(String userid)throws SQLException{
    open();
    Cursor cursor = SQLdb.query(DATABASE_USERS,COLUMNS,KEY_USERID+"="+userid,null,null,null,null);
    close();
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor getPassword(String password)throws SQLException{
    open();
    Cursor cursor = SQLdb.query(DATABASE_USERS,COLUMNS,KEY_PASSWORD+"="+password,null,null,null,null);
    close();
    return cursor;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: post your logcat in brief

Comment: Please also attach your log. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your string literals actually literals and not column names. Change

```
SQLdb.query(DATABASE_USERS,COLUMNS,KEY_USERID+"="+userid,null,null,null,null);
```

to something like

```
SQLdb.query(DATABASE_USERS,COLUMNS,KEY_USERID+"=?",new String[]{ userid },null,null,null);
```

and similarly for the other query.